# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, widget

What is the problem of this code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/cart.dart' show Cart;
import '../widgets/cart_item.dart';
import '../providers/orders.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/cart';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Cart'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Chip(
                    label: Text(
                      '\$${cart.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('ORDER NOW'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false).addOrder(
                        cart.items.values.toList(),
                        cart.totalAmount,
                      );
                      cart.clear();
                    },
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              
              itemCount: cart.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItem(
                    
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                    cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                    cart.items.values.toList()[i].title,
                  ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I see inside the `DEBUG CONSOLE`:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
> while applying parent data.: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept
> ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly
> inside Flex widgets. The offending Expanded is currently placed inside
> a FractionalTranslation widget.
>
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
> incompatible parent data was:   Semantics ← Card ← Expanded ←
> FractionalTranslation ← SlideTransition ← Stack ← Listener ←
> _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← ⋯ When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

EDIT: I think maybe the error happens at this code:

```
class CartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String productId;
  final double price;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;

  CartItem(
    this.id,
    this.productId,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.title,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
      background: Container(
        // color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
      },
      child: Expanded(
        child: Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 15,
            vertical: 4,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      '\$$price',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Total: \$${(price * quantity)}'),
              trailing: Text('$quantity x'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Expanded can only be the child of flex widgets (typically Row or Column). The error is telling you there is an Expanded as a child to Card. Probably inside the CartItem widget you created. The error is not in visible in the code you pasted.

Comment: @Shannon: How can I find the code the error happens there?

Comment: @Shannon: I added the `cartItem.dart`  code to the EDIT part of my question.  `Expanded` is a child of `Dismissible` in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the expanded widgets in the child of flex widgets. Basically, the error shows an expanded widget as a child to a card widget. But it is not visible in your code.
The problem is with your card widget being wrapped with an expanded widget. Removing the expanded widget will solve the issue.

**Updated code for your cartItem.dart**

```
class CartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String productId;
  final double price;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;

  CartItem(
    this.id,
    this.productId,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.title,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
      background: Container(
        // color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      onDismissed: (direction) {},
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    '\$$price',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            subtitle: Text('Total: \$${(price * quantity)}'),
            trailing: Text('$quantity x'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I find the code the error happens there?

Comment: I added the `cartItem.dart`  code to the EDIT part of my question.  `Expanded` is a child of `Dismissible` in there.

Comment: Check now I have updated the cartItem.dart code. Let me know if this works.